# Undefined error in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

Why I'm getting undefined error in Firefox and IE. This code works well in Google Chrome. Here is the full code http://liveweave.com/fUhpiI

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="css/hpstyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/hpjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="hp">
    <div>
    <h2>1. Which one do you prefer?</h2>
    <div>   
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="radio1" class="radio" value="9"/>
        <label for="radio1">Tea</label>
    </div>
    <div>   
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="radio2" class="radio" value="4"/>
        <label for="radio2">Coffee</label>
    </div>
    <div>   
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="radio3" class="radio" value="1"/>
        <label for="radio3">Milk</label>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div>
    </br>
    <div><div>
    <button type="button" onclick="hp(this.form)">Check</button>
    <input class="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </div></div></div>
</form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="total"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is javascript

```
function hp(form)
{
var count1=0, count2=0, count3=0, count4=0, count5=0, count6=0, count7=0, count8=0, count9=0, count10=0,a ;
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
if (form.q1[i].checked === true)
{
count1++;
}
}
if(count1!==1){
alert("Please Answer 1st Question");
return false;
}
answer1 = (form.q1.value);
a=Math.floor(answer1);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= "The selected values are "+"</br>"+answer1;
}
```

Comment: what is this? Nobody is going to that site... post your code in the question itself.

Comment: What “undefined error”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should declare a answer variable .and you should access "q1" elements by giving index  since you have 3 "q1" elements .basically `form.q1` is a `object NodeList` .you can't get value from `object NodeList`.so actually in your case you should add brake to for loop and find the clicked radio button index .

you should use

```
answer1 = form.q1[i].value;
```

instead of

```
answer1 = form.q1.value;
```

---

explain

`form.q1` is a `object NodeList` so

```
form.q1.value --> undefined since object NodeList/collection has no property "value"
```

and

```
form.q1[0] --> HTMLInputElement so

form.q1[0].value --> is not undefined
```

fixed code .[WORKING DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/madhawa11111/3rywkdvf/](http://jsfiddle.net/madhawa11111/3rywkdvf/)

```
function hp(form) {
    var i;
    var answer;
    var count1 = 0,count2 = 0,count3 = 0,count4 = 0,count5 = 0,count6 = 0,count7 = 0,count8 = 0,count9 = 0,count10 = 0, a;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (form.q1[i].checked === true) {
            count1++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count1 !== 1) {
        alert("Please Answer 1st Question");
        return false;
    }
    answer1 = form.q1[i].value; //error was here .
    a = Math.floor(answer1);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The selected values are " + "</br>" + answer1;
}
```

if it worked in google chorm that's because browsers ignore some errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such awesome explanation. Edited code is working fine. Problem solved